# VB 6.0 windows service on Windows Server 2012

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2012, windows-nt

I have couple of windows service written in VB 6.0... FOr many years these services are successfully running on windows server 2003, Now its time for windows server 2012 in my organisation.. I am able to install the VB 6.0 windows service application using the CB 6.0 package on windows server 2012, but unable to install the service from the command prompt. I tried below to install the service, command is executing without any errors but service is not reflecting in Services.msc

Command:
xxx.exe -install

Comment: Either rewrite it using a modern language (vb.net or C#) or if possible run the app in a VM.

Comment: VB6 runtime is [fully supported](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikosan/2012/04/20/support-statement-for-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-8-updated/) on Windows Server 2012 which is encouraging. Try to get further information on where it is failing. Is there any logging in your VB6 service application?

Comment: Could this be as simple as a UAC problem?  Are you using an elevated command prompt?